# Can't find Module bridgeclient on my python2.7 [mac]

Tags: python, arduino, bridge

I'm really new on python/bridge/....
I want to execute a code like this:
[image: code that I want to execute]

But I have the following result:

[image: result]

I have installed python2.7 on my Mac, but I cannot find the module bridge on /usr/lib/python2.7/bridge/

Do you know where I can find it? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried 'pip install bridgeclient' ?

Comment: I've tried and this is the result:

Collecting bridgeclient
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bridgeclient (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for bridgeclient

Comment: check what is the real module name and if it can be downloaded by pip